# Filter out a record depending upon other records of the same ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

My table schema is like follow:

```
Table Name: Quality

ID     Name      Type
--     ----      ----
1      XYZ       S1
1      XYZ       B1
1      XYZ       S2
1      XYZ       R1
2      ABC       B1
2      ABC       B2
2      ABC       R1 
2      ABC       U1
3      PQR       B1
3      PQR       B2
3      PQR       R2
3      PQR       R1
4      AAA       B1
4      AAA       S1
5      BBB       B1
5      BBB       B2
5      BBB       U2
```

I want to filter out those IDs whose Type is B1 but it should not be (R1 and U1 in other rows). Also those IDs whose type is B2 but it shuld not be (R2 and S2 in other rows)

here,the output should be

```
ID     Name      Type
--     ----      ----
2      ABC       B2
4      AAA       B1
5      BBB       B1
```

My query is following which is nto giving proper result:

```
SELECT 
      ID , NAME , TYPE      

FROM
       QUALITY Q

WHERE
       (Q.TYPE IN ('B1') AND (Q.TYPE Not IN ('R1', 'U1'))
       OR
       (Q.TYPE IN ('B2') AND (Q.TYPE Not IN ('R2', 'U2'))
```

My query runs for one record at a time so i am not getting proper result. how can I make this query check every record of that particular ID to find TYPE?

Any help will be really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Quality q
WHERE
    (Type = 'B1' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Quality WHERE ID = q.ID AND Type IN ('R1', 'U1')))
    OR (Type = 'B2' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Quality WHERE ID = q.ID AND Type IN ('R2', 'U2')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
quality q 
where 
(q.type = 'b1' and q.id not in (select q2.id from quality q2 where q2.type in ('r1','u1'))
or
(q.type = 'b2' and q.id not in (select q3.id from quality q3 where q3.type in ('r2','u2'))
```

Comment: Please explain how this code provides a solution to the question. This helps the OP understand and future searchers.